# Regular expression that would contains a number less then or equal to 20

Tags: regex

I need the regular expression that would return true if the string contains a number less then or equal to 20 and only allow the use of numbers.

Comment: Number? As in integer or float? Is it signed or unsigned? Also what language is this regex supposed to be used in?

Comment: The last nhahtdh's question is very important because every language and every third party regex library has it's own syntax, slightly different from all others. Some even don't recognize `(`, `)` and `+` as control characters unless preceded by `\ ` while others interpret `\(` as literal ( and `(` as a control character.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are matching numbers which are:

- Integers
- Within the range of [0,20]

This should work: `^(([01]?[0-9])|(20))$`.

If you are matching floats, things get a bit messier. Checking numeric ranges should, ideally, always be done through your platform's numeric operators.

Comment: You don't need the inner parentheses. Apart from that, +1.

Comment: Thanks. It works for 0 to 20. But if i want to use this regx as profileProperty.^(([01]?[0-9])|(20))$.id and want to match profileProperty.1.id or profileProperty.20.id it doesn't work. Need your more help...

Comment: @Nadeem: What you are saying seems to be language specific. A language which it seems I have never encountered. You will need to provide more information or ask a new question.

Comment: you can also say this, it is requirement specific. I am using following code to validate this regx. `code`   Pattern propertyPattern = Pattern.compile("profileProperty.^(([01]?[0-9])|(20))$.id");
  
  Matcher matcher = propertyPattern.matcher("profileProperty.20.id");
  boolean matchFound = matcher.lookingAt();
  if (matchFound)
   System.out.println("found.."); `code`

Comment: it works for me `code` profileProperty.(?:\\b)([0-9]|1[0-9]|20)\\b.id `code` Thanks.

Comment: @Nadeem: The `^` and `$` anchors define the start and end of the string. The way you did it in your comment will not work. Also, the `.` in regular expression language is a reserved character (it means match any character) so it needs to be escaped like so: `\.`. Glad this worked out for you. If this answer was what you where after, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

**This would match integers less than or equal to 20**

```
(?:\b|-)0*([0-9]|1[0-9]|20)\b
```

**Explanation**

```
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \b             # Assert position at a word boundary
   |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      -              # Match the character “-” literally
)
0              # Match the character “0” literally
   *              # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(              # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      [0-9]          # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      1              # Match the character “1” literally
      [0-9]          # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   |              # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      20             # Match the characters “20” literally
)
\b             # Assert position at a word boundary
```

**Visit [here](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) for future problems.**

Comment: After some modifications as per my requirement it works for me `code` profileProperty.(?:\\b)([0-9]|1[0-9]|20)\\b.id `code` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the language that supports the regex. I will assume that it uses some variants of PCRE.

The code here is to strictly validate the string **only** contains the number.

Only integer, assuming non-negative, no leading 0's:

```
^(1?\d|20)$
```

Only integer, assuming non-negative, allow arbitrary leading 0's:

```
^0*(1?\d|20)$
```

Any integer, no leading 0's:

```
^(+?(1?\d|20)|-\d+)$
```

Any integer, allow arbitrary leading 0's:

```
^(+?0*(1?\d|20)|-\d+)$
```

If the number is not arbitrary large, it is better if you capture the number with a loose regex `\b[+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?\b`, then convert it to number and check it.

Answer (score 1):

`(\b[0-9]\b|\b1[0-9]\b|\b20\b)`  worked for me

Only integer, assuming non-negative, no leading 0's

I used to to find percentages less than 20, so it end up being:

`(\b[0-9]%|\b1[0-9]%|\b20%)`